# using python script in CDATA in xml

Tags: python, xml, cdata

I am having a scenario where I need to call a python script from within a CDATA section in a xml file. Just wanted to know if this is supported? and is there any way I can validate that it works? What I mean is, something like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<page>
<content><![CDATA[
/usr/bin/python /home/user/hello.py >> /home/user/out.log 2>&1
]]>
</content>
</page>
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: What should support this ? What do you want to validate ?

Comment: I wanted to know if we can call a python script within a CDATA section in xml. Is that allowed in CDATA? And, if there are any issues with the line - /usr/bin/python /home/user/hello.py >> /home/user/out.log , does xml show up as an error?

Comment: More specifically, can I see the run of the hello.py script somehow when I call into the xml?

Comment: What do you mean by *call into the xml*?

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear. I mean, whenever we call that xml, we need to run the CDATA section, right? Which means it should call the python script? How do I know that the python script is getting executed? Isnt the CDATA section supposed to have code that can be executed?